# How to initialize a struct with random data in C?

Tags: c, unit-testing, struct, storage

Assuming we have the following complex struct (in C). It includes fixed-length arrays, members of varying sizes, enums and other structs. This struct is not packed, and cannot be packed.

```
struct {
    uint8_t smallNum;
    /* uint8_t align0 */
    /* uint8_t align1 */
    /* uint8_t align2 */
    uint32_t arrayOfBigNums[5];
    bool isFalse;
    /* uint8_t align0 */
    /* uint8_t align1 */
    /* uint8_t align2 */
    struct myOtherStruct;
    /* uint8_t align0 */
    enum mySmallEnum;
...
    uint8_t aByte;
    /* uint8_t align0 */
    /* uint8_t align1 */
} myStruct;
```

We would like to initialize this struct with random data for unit testing. The test includes taking this struct, serializing it, writing it to flash, reading it, deserializing it, and then checking that the data hasn't changed.

Either generate all possible values, or generate a small randomized subset and test it. So how would one go about doing this?

The immediate solution would be the following:

```
myStruct testData = {0};
myStruct readData = {0};
testData.smallNum = rand();
testData.arrayOfBigNums[0] = rand();
testData.arrayOfBigNums[1] = rand();
....
testData.aByte = rand();
save(&testData);
load(&readData);
int ret = memcmp(&readData, &testData, sizeof(myStruct)); 
// ret == 0. Good!
```

But this solution isn't scalable. Adding another field to the struct, or increasing the array would require changing the unit test. Also, it'd be a long init function, prone to human error.

Another solution would be to generate a random array of bytes, and then `memcpy` it into our struct. Although this is a great idea, in practice it won't work because our struct isn't packed. Some bytes are and always will be 0.

```
myStruct testData = {0};
myStruct readData = {0};
uint8_t* randomData = genRandomData(sizeof(myStruct));
memcpy((uint8_t*)&testData, randomData, sizeof(myStruct));
save(&testData);
load(&readData);
int ret = memcmp(&readData, &testData, sizeof(myStruct)); 
// ret != 0 because deserialization will fill the struct properly. 
// Ignoring junk bytes in padding
```

My current working solution is to iteratively improve on the previous one. Initialize a struct with 0xff, cast it to a byte array and mask it with everything. [You get a compiler warning](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/gcc/patch/573D050A.7030100@gmail.com/) but to my knowledge it's harmless.

```
myStruct structMask = {MACRO_TO_FILL_WITH_MANY(-1)};
myStruct testData = {0};
myStruct readData = {0};
uint8_t* randomData = genRandomData(sizeof(myStruct));
memcpy((uint8_t*)&testData, randomData, sizeof(myStruct));
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(myStruct); i++){
    ((uint8_t*)&testData)[i] &= ((uint8_t*)&structMask)[i];
}
save(&testData);
load(&readData);
int ret = memcmp(&readData, &testData, sizeof(myStruct)); 
// ret != 0 because deserialization will fill the struct properly. 
// Ignoring junk bytes in padding
```

This solution is also not optimal, because it doesn't take into account enum limitations. Types like bool (from stdbool.h) are stored as 0/1 which is nice, but enums can still have undefined values. So we'd need to manually modulo all enum values.

Looking for more generic / robust solutions.

Comment: When only certain bits (of byte, word...) are interesting, one uses a bit mask... To get around the de-serialised problem, fill the initial buffer with random bits, then iterate byte-wise masking to leave only data regions non-zero, then serialise it and send it off... memset the mask block to NULLs, then memset each member to 0XFF. Creating the mask is an extra 'maintenance point' but should work...

Comment: So you want random, but not random, because "Some bytes are and always will be 0." and "bool (from stdbool.h) are stored as 0/1" and "doesn't take into account enum limitations". So it's not random - it's clearly type aware and constraint aware. Write the function to initilaize it. `But this solution isn't scalable` It is. You just have to throw more developers. You can't have the cake and eat the cake. `Looking for more generic` Write a python program that uses C source code and generates the constructor. Code generation will be the kind of answers you could get.

Comment: @KamilCuk You can be random and constraint aware. If I tell you to give me a random number between 1 and 1000, it's still a random number.

Comment: I don't quite understand well all (because english is not my main language) but how about writing a function that compare two struct instead of using memcmp ? Like strcmp do with string ?
That way, you can initialize your testData with random value byte per byte and don't worrying about your padding value ?

Comment: Since this is for testing, `memset` both structures to zero (to initialize all the data, including the padding, `{0}` only initializes members not padding). Then initialize member-wise to whatever random values you need (don't even need `rand` here, just some fixed hard-coded specific values are fine). And then to a byte-wise `memcmp` after saving and loading.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As shown in the question, the problem is that there are lots of members. There are members that are themselves structs. If you flatten the entire struct down to its' primitive members, you may have 1000+ members.

Comment: Then I would argue that you have a flawed design. What is the actual use of this structure?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can't argue with that ;) It's essentially a context, holding all information for a given routine to run properly. It's deserialized from flash storage, changed a bit, and then serialized again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I actually found the answer to my own question. The main problem is that there isn't an initializer for my struct. However, *there already exist* serialization functions. So we can use the non-working second solution, and convert it to a working solution.

So a much cleaner solution would be:

```
myStruct testData = {0};
myStruct readData = {0};
uint8_t* randomData = genRandomData(sizeof(myStruct));
memcpy(&testData, randomData, sizeof(myStruct));
save(&testData);
load(&readData); // readData is now a valid random struct.

myStruct realReadData = {0}
save(&readData);
load(&realReadData);

memcmp(readReadData, readData, sizeof(myStruct)); // This does equal 0 if serialize/deserialize functions are correct.
```

If there's an issue in serialize/deserialize functions, the input struct (corrupt as it may be) should provide different results.

Comment: That seem good, but if your save/load function overwrite a valid memory space (like the end of `testData.arrayOfBigNums`), you will not see it. Be carefull of this case.

Comment: If it overwrites a valid space it will affect the next member (`isFalse` in this case). So the test will fail. The only issue I can think of is when it writes 2 bytes into `isFalse` and then the missing byte is hidden in the padding. So that's definitely a caveat.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you want the random data to obey by the rules of the types, there is no way to make that work in a scalable manner.

What I would do is to just copy random bytes into the struct. Yes, some data is going to be invalid, and that too should be a test case to see how you handle corrupted/invalid data:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Foo {
    int a;
    double d;
    char ch;
    _Bool b;
};

int main() {
    FILE* random = fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb");
    struct Foo foo;

    if (!random || fread(&foo, sizeof(foo), 1, random) != 1) {
        fputs("Failed to generate random data", stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    
    fclose(random);

    printf("foo.d = %d\n", foo.d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C programming does not have reflection. In C, you would write a normal initialization function where manually for every member you initialize the struct.

I would just write a macro `CHOOSE_RANDOM` that will choose a random from a set of values and initialize the struct random with `memset` and then limit the members that have some constraints.

> But this solution isn't scalable
>
> Looking for more generic / robust solutions.

It is said that AI is so smart it will replace developers in the future. Write a program that inspects your C source code and generates the initialization function. Such a program, because it would be outside C, will be able to inspect the source code and make type aware decisions.

The following python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pycparser import parse_file, c_ast
import tempfile
import os

text = r"""
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

enum mySmallEnum { A, B, C };

struct {
    uint8_t aByte;
    bool isFalse;
    enum mySmallEnum myenum;
} myStruct;


"""

structname = "myStruct";

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w') as tmp:
    tmp.write(text)
    tmp.flush()
    ast = parse_file(tmp.name, use_cpp=True)
    for a in ast:
        if isinstance(a, c_ast.Decl) and a.name == structname:
            members = a.type.type.decls
            print("// Initialize {}".format(structname))
            for d in members:
                name = d.type.declname
                type = d.type.type
                if isinstance(type, c_ast.IdentifierType):
                    type = type.names[0]
                    if type == "uint8_t":
                        print("{}.{} = rand();".format(structname, name))
                    elif type == "_Bool":
                        print("{}.{} = rand() ? 1 : 0;".format(structname, name))
                    else:
                        assert 0, "TODO"
                elif isinstance(type, c_ast.Enum):
                    typename = type.name
                    vals = []
                    for a in ast:
                        if isinstance(a, c_ast.Decl) and isinstance(a.type, c_ast.Enum) and a.type.name == typename:
                            vals += [x.name for x in a.type.values.enumerators]
                            break
                    print("{}.{} = CHOOSE_RANDOM({});".format(structname, name, ', '.join(vals)))
                else:
                    assert 0, "TODO"
```

outputs:

```
// Initialize myStruct
myStruct.aByte = rand();
myStruct.isFalse = rand() ? 1 : 0;
myStruct.myenum = CHOOSE_RANDOM(A, B, C);
```

Comment: neat ! Is the file parsing done by `parse_file` really parse C syntaxte or it's C++ (like use_cpp=True seem to hint) ? Where is the python documentation for this function ?
Can you theorically parse a complete source code ?

Comment: https://github.com/eliben/pycparser `Can you theorically parse a complete source code ?` Theoretically, you can write your own g++ and parse everything. I have written a program in ~20mins to only showcase it's possible. I think using clang AST will be more robust than python. `like use_cpp=True` pycparser is not able to parse `#include`s, so it calls `cpp` to run preprocessor and then parses.

Comment: That's a cool solution! However, it relies on third parties (python in this case, and pycparser as a dependency). I think in most cases, if it's entirely not possible to do with C - you could definitely do it this way. Keep in mind that pycparser has its' limitations though. If your code is a bit more complex (think 20+ headers, some not well formatted and with macros), problems arise. Speaking from experience, as I've worked with pycparser for a different thing :)